# Huge margin when using matplotlib supxlabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a common label in a matplotlib's subplots, but I am having some troubles.

I am using python 3.10 and matplotlib 3.5.1

There is a minimal working example illustrating the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(8, 12),  sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.supxlabel('Example of supxlabel')
fig.supylabel('Example of supylabel')
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

This code generates the following figure:

[image: this figure]

Note the huge ugly margins above `'Example of supxlabel'` and right to `'Example of supylabel'`.

I tried to use the option `constrained_layout=True`, along with `fig.set_constrained_layout_pads`, but it didn't solve my problem.

I know that the problem can be solved using the option `x`, `y`, `va` and `ha` of `supxlabel` and `supylabel`, but I have many figures to generate and cannot realistically find and set the values of these options manually.

Comment: try a plt.tight_layout(), you can check the options you can vary the different pads automatically

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: simplest is `plt.subplots(layout='constrained')`, works very nicely for all sorts of manipulations; below is if full control is desired, which `'constrained'` (from what I can tell) won't permit.

---

My current workaround is `y = np.sqrt(height) / 100 * 2.2`, which seems to work well at least for `height` from 5 to 25. If using `subplots_adjust(bottom=)`, a constant adjustment factor seems to work, like `y -= .04`. I've opened an [Issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25231).

```py
width = 10
height = 20
y = np.sqrt(height) / 100 * 2.2
fig, _ = plt.subplots(23, 1, figsize=(width, height))
fig.supxlabel("supxlabel", y=y)
```

[image]

Comment: Just call `fig.tight_layout()` before `fig.supxlabel('label')`. No need to adjust `y` or `x`.

Comment: I don't think that works in general from what I've tried, but `layout='constrained'` mostly will